# Как запомнить случаи постановки тире и двоеточия?

Tags: пунктуация, правила

Вопрос у меня общий, широкий, однако я надеюсь на какой-то полезный совет.

С пунктуацией у меня вроде серьёзных проблем не возникает, обычно знаю, как правильно расставить запятые, не обращаясь ни к чему, но когда речь заходит о ***тире и двоеточии,*** как правило, возникают проблемы. Приходится лезть в правила, где случаев постановки либо тире, либо двоеточия в отдельности не по одному десятку. Запомнить их все я не в состоянии.

*Может кто-то порекомендовать источник, где количество случаев постановки этих знаков сведено к минимуму, но при этом имеющиеся случаи удачно сформулированы (хорошо, легко для запоминания) и охватывают все вместе весь (или почти весь) спектр примеров употребления каждого из этих знаков?*

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Артем, посмотрите, может, вам поможет этот учебник. По-моему, там все предельно ясно  сформулировано. http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/

Comment: Спасибо, Серж, но там только частный случай про тире и ничего о двоеточии. Или тире только и ставится, что между подлежащим и сказуемым. Не могу так сходу сообразить. Почитаю теперь, что Людмила написала.

Comment: Вон Людмила нашла. Это тот же учебник.

Comment: А-а, тот же? Спасибо! Вникаю вот.))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Мне нравится [на Грамоте](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_185):

*Двоеточие в БСС в основном пишется при:*

• Пояснении (можно заменить  на "а именно")

• Изъяснении (можно подставить "что": *и увидел, что; и услышал, что* и так далее)

• Указании причины (можно подставить "потому что")

• Прямом вопросе (например: *ответьте себе на вопрос: растёт ли на земле зло?*)

*Тире ставится при:*

• Быстрой смене событий (заменить на "и")

• Противопоставлении или сопоставлении (заменить на "а", "но" или "чем — тем" )

• Сравнении (как, как будто)

• Результате (поэтому)

• Условии или времени (заменить на "если" или "когда")

И вот такое примечание.

Для разграничения случаев постановки двоеточия и тире в бессоюзных сложных предложениях можно исходить из следующего общего положения:

если основная часть высказывания (соответствующая главному предложению в сложноподчиненных предложениях) заключена в первой части, а во второй (соответствующей придаточному предложению в сложноподчиненных предложениях) содержится пояснение, раскрытие содержания первой части, изложение какого-либо факта, указание на причину, то между частями ставится двоеточие;

если же, наоборот, основная часть высказывания заключена во второй части, а первая имеет подчиненное по смыслу значение (указывает время, условие и т. д.), то между частями ставится тире.

Ср.: Выйти невозможно: на улице проливной дождь (основное высказывание содержится в первой части, во второй указывается причина). – На улице проливной дождь – выйти невозможно (причина указывается в первой части, во второй следствие, вывод, что составляет основу высказывания). Ср. также при сохранении того же порядка частей бессоюзного сложного предложения: Молодёжь ушла: на вечере стало скучно (ушла, *потому что* стало скучно). Молодёжь ушла – на вечере стало скучно (ушла, *поэтому* стало скучно).

Comment: Спасибо огромное, Людмила!!! А много пробелов вначале специально или случайно у Вас?

Comment: Людмила, а можете привести пример на сравнение с "как" или "как будто"? И ещё не могу понять, когда в случае с "чем — тем" нужна просто запятая, а когда тире.

Comment: Про сравнение вроде уже понял ("берёза" у Сибиллы).

Comment: Союз ЧЕМ...ТЕМ относится к СПП с придаточными сопоставительными, обычно всегда ставится запятая, тире как авторский знак при наличии паузы: Колючие глаза Римского через стол врезались в лицо администратора, и чем дальше тот говорил, тем мрачнее становились эти глаза. [М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита, часть 1 (1929-1940)].  Но и рисунки не помогли, и чем дальше― тем путанее и непонятнее становилось заявление поэта. [М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита, часть 1 (1929-1940)]

Answer (score 3):

Во всех учебниках много правил, не связанных какой-либо общей идеей, и при выборе знака  их приходится последовательно перебирать. Поэтому **лучше составить для себя конспект и пользоваться им.**

**1) Интонация помогает правильно выбрать знак**

Существуют **два вида тире**: разделительное  и присоединительное. **Разделительное** тире с восходяще-нисходящей интонацией чётко делит предложение на две части. **Присоединительное** тире имеет нисходяще-нисходящую интонацию, которая от **пояснительной интонации (тоже нисходяще-нисходящей)**, характерной для  двоеточия, отличается подчеркнутой паузой (поэтому  именно присоединительное тире часто замещает двоеточие).

**2) Для тире характерны две темы:**

а) **Аналог ССП (разделительная интонция):** БСП является аналогом ССП с пропущенными союзами ***А, НО, И***; значение **сопоставления, противопоставления, резкий переход, разная структура предложений**: Служить бы рад – прислуживаться тошно.  Ввысь взлетает сокол – жмётся уж к земле. Семь раз отмерь – один раз отрежь.   Прошла неделя, другая – вдруг въезжает ко мне на двор коляска. Ещё мгновенье – нет ответа.

б) **Прямая последовательность событий:** БСП является аналогом СПП с пропущенными подчинительными союзами и прямой последовательностью событий: **время – событие, условие –  событие, причина – событие, факт – вывод, обобщение, факт – сравнение**. Разделительная интонация: Распахнули окна – запах сена вступил на веранду. Дела не любишь – мастером не будешь. Не было возможности уйти незаметно – он вышел открыто.  Берёза в лесу без вершины – хозяйка без мужа в дому. Присоединительная интонация: Кругом ярко светит солнце – поохотиться ещё можно. Дорога была плохая – людей в кузове швыряло из стороны в сторону.

**3) Для двоеточия характерны три темы (пояснительная интонация):**

**а) Изъяснительное значение:** Я выпрыгнул из кибитки и вижу: матушка встречает меня с видом глубокого огорчения. Оборачиваюсь: Грушницкий!  Я выглянул из кибитки: всё было мрак и вихорь. Мы с удивлением спрашивали: неужели Сильвио не будет драться?

**б) Пояснительное значение:** А к нам идёт угрюмая зима: засохла степь, лес  глохнет и желтеет. Одного я не понимаю: как она могла тебя укусить?

**в) Обратная последовательность событий:** Печален я: со мною друга нет. Над Герасимом, однако, глумиться не решались: он шуток не любил. Грушницкий не вынес этого удара: как все мальчики,  он имеет претензию быть стариком. Художник – зеркало своей среды: в нём отражается его общество, нация и время.

**4) Указательные местоимения при различении тире и двоеточия**

**Тире:** местоимения во второй части отсылают к первой части:  Не надо торопиться – я **так** понимаю эту ситуацию. **Двоеточие:** местоимения в первой части отсылают ко второй части:  Я понимаю эту ситуацию **так**: не надо торопиться.

Тире: Всё время слышался шум воды – **это** рядом с дорогой текла река. Идти вперёд или погибнуть – **так** стоял вопрос. Времени мало – **вот что** плохо. Двоеточие: Невежды судят **так**: в чём толку не поймут, то всё у них пустяк. **Таких** примеров много в мире: не любит узнавать себя никто в сатире.

**5)  Замена двоеточия присоединительным тире**

Для современного языка характерна замена двоеточия тире во всех его значениях, то есть для выражения изъяснительных, пояснительных и следственно-причинных  отношений.   **Для пояснительных и следственно-причинных отношений** не указывается  обратный порядок значений, характерный для двоеточия, а указывается только взаимообусловленность предикативных частей.  **Для изъяснительных отношений** замена связана с определёнными особенностями (ускоренный темп речи, отсутствие увеличенной паузы, эффект присутствия автора):

Вижу – дело плохо! Ясно одно – оставаться здесь опасно. Иногда я думаю – надо бежать. Оглянулся – за ним стоял Серёжа в длинной рубашке, босой и с завязанным горлом. Всё стало понятно – на поляне кормилась лошадь, а где-то здесь, рядом, кто-то ночевал. На этой земле никто не захотел селиться – она оказалась слишком скудной. Пора ехать – всё уже готово.

Comment: *...и при выборе знака их приходится последовательно перебирать.* Вот именно, в этом и проблема!! А ещё в том, что, как Вы правильно подметили, тире вытесняет двоеточие, и реальные примеры мало чему учат. В теории одно, а видишь совсем другое, так что только с толку примеры сбивают. *Читаю дальше...*

Comment: Спасибо большое, ещё читаю пока!!! Возник ещё вопрос: два случая с присоединительной интонацией в 2б относятся к какому-то варианту из выделенных жирным (в том же абзаце)?

Comment: Ещё раз большое спасибо, отличный у Вас получился конспект (сам бы так не смог)!!! ;) Можно я в 2б интонации курсивом выделю, чтобы легче воспринималось (буду ещё не раз перечитывать)? Хочу принять Ваш ответ, но уже принял другой :(( (нехорошо Людмилу минусовать) И главный вопрос: *чему Вы следуете и советуете следовать при выборе: старым правилам или новым тенденциям?*

Comment: Присоединительная интонация: Кругом ярко светит солнце – поохотиться ещё можно (факт-вывод). Дорога была плохая – людей в кузове швыряло из стороны в сторону (причина - следствие). Если текст учебный, то лучше пользоваться классическими правилами. В свободном варианте зависит  от контекста:  двоеточие ставлю, если чувствуется необходимость пояснительной паузы.  Еще интересно отметить, что вместо двоеточия и присоединительного тире мы в обычных записях пользуемся присоединительной ЗАПЯТОЙ.

Comment: Дело в том, что предложения часто неоднородны, связаны между собой по смыслу, и  большое количество тире и двоеточий не украсит текст, да и особо напрягаться нет смысла, фиксируя все причинно-следственные отношения. Также в пословицах часто ставится запятая, например: Дорог не подарок,  дорого внимание. Хочешь есть калачи, так не сиди на печи. Работа не волк, в лес  не убежит.

Comment: Спасибо, Сибилла, утешили.)) Я-то заменяю запятой, когда не знаю, подойдёт двоеточие или тире, и что именно подойдёт, если да.

Comment: Сибилла, а Вы не можете мне ответить ещё на вопрос к Людмиле про "чем — тем", раз она не отвечает? Спасибо!