# Что поставить: тире или двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте. Как написать правильно: "Я решил провести эксперимент: проверить реакцию X на Y" или "Я решил провести эксперимент ─ проверить реакцию X на Y"?

Answer (score 5):

**Я решил провести эксперимент ─ проверить реакцию X на Y.**

***Определение, выраженное инфинитивом с зависимыми словами, находится в конце предложения, поэтому ставим тире.***

ПАС Лопатина **об условиях постановки тире**: *"Обособленные инфинитивные определения, распространенные и нераспространенные, располагаются в конце предложения:
... **А почему бы вам, скажем, не задаться простой и очень важной целью — сэкономить средства, выделенные государством вашей школе** (газ.)"* [Справочник п/р Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=155)

Answer (score 3):

Оба варианта возможны, выбор зависит от контекста.

Данную грамматическую конструкцию можно рассматривать различным образом:
а) как пояснение: решил (что сделать?) "провести эксперимент", а именно "проверить". б) как несогласованное определение: решил провести эксперимент (какой?).

**У Розенталя:** При отсутствии пояснительного союза вместо запятой перед пояснительным членом предложения часто ставится тире: "Иногда что-нибудь **хочется сделать — почитать"**. Возможна **также постановка двоеточия** (чтобы избежать двух тире): "Предложен и другой путь: использование некоторых видов морских растений — водорослей, богатых многими ценными веществами". Можно заметить, что предложение и без заключительной части  смотрится вполне корректно, в том числе с точки зрения интонации:  Предложен и другой путь: использование некоторых видов морских растений.

(1) Я решил **провести  эксперимент**: **проверить** реакцию X на Y.  Логически выделена вторая часть, **поясняющая** первую, двоеточие, наличие паузы, предупреждающей о дальнейшем пояснении.

(2) **Я решил провести эксперимент** ─ проверить реакцию X на Y. Выделяется первая часть, вторая часть является обособленным несогласованным определением.

Comment: Сибилла, будьте добры, объясните, пожалуйста! Не могу понять, то ли Ваши слова из этого ответа про выделение частей действительно противоречат со второй половиной ответа Людмилы в моём вопросе про тире и двоеточие (http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427443/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F), то ли то, что Вы говорите и она, надо понимать по разному.

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, как и те, и другие слова в комплексе воспринять правильно. Спасибо!

Comment: Артем, насколько я понимаю, Людмила сравнивает БСП и СПП: выделяет главное и придаточное в СПП и по аналогии выделяет главную и придаточную часть в БСП. Всё это в какой-то мере формально и  касается сложных предложений. Здесь у нас простое осложненное предложение, и принцип выделения главного немного другой. Поставили двоеточие - значит, внимание переключили на содержание второй части. Поставили тире - значит,  вторая часть является присоединительной.

Comment: Еще интересный момент по данному примеру. Классическое несогласованное определение относится к существительному: Он послал адъютанта с приказанием (каким?)  атаковать французов (нет знаков). Но прекрасен ДАННЫЙ жребий – просиять и умереть (тире ставится при пояснении уже имеющегося определения). Поэтому наш вариант не очень-то похож на определение, скорее здесь пояснительные отношения между глагольными частями сказуемого.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Сибилла! А Ирина вообще считает, что двоеточие может соединять только два полноценных предложения: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427768/%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5. Я привёл пример перечисления в комментарии к Людмилиному ответу, но никто это никак не прокомментировал. Она (Ирина) неправа ведь в этом?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.